Align copyright symbol with text
What is the correct way to display a copyright symbol so that its surrounding circle is aligned with the text. The result should look like this:


No answer, an observation, NOT intended for conversation: I'd say: it is ...  Please add to your question what kind of alignment you'd expect instead.

Wrt daleif's comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif I suggest to add also the code (which compiles), which gives this result. So we don't have to guess. Thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The image provided in my question is from a PDF document and i tried (without success) to replicate the style of the copyright symbol as shown above. I don't have the code which compiles to the output above.

@skoestlmeier You could show what you tried. This would make your question look less like a do-it-for-me post.

Note that a unicode engine like lualatex will typeset © like the OP wants. But pdflatex does not (as it is not unicode aware). Here is a bit of code to make an adjusted copyright symbol.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\FooBar{}
{
  \box_clear:N \l_tmpa_box
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { C }
  \box_clear:N \l_tmpb_box
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpb_box { \raisebox{\depth}{\textcopyright} }
  \box_resize_to_ht:Nn \l_tmpb_box { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \box_use:N \l_tmpb_box
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.1pt}}%
\rlap{\raisebox{7pt}{\rule{10cm}{0.1pt}}}%
Copyright C\copyright C\FooBar

\end{document}

The
\leavevmode\rlap{\rule{10cm}{0.1pt}}%
\rlap{\raisebox{7pt}{\rule{10cm}{0.1pt}}}%

can be removed, it is just to show the sizes.

The image is from pdflatex.

You could use the scalerel package to match the size with C.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\mycopyright}{\scalerel*{\copyright}{C}}

\begin{document}

Copyright \mycopyright

\end{document}


I add a small overshoot below the baseline.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Copyright}{}{%
  \raisebox{-0.1ex}{%
    \resizebox{!}{\dimeval{0.2ex+\fontcharht\font`A}}{%
      \raisebox{\depth}{\textcopyright}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\show\latextextcopyright

\subsubsection*{The new}

Copyright \Copyright

\subsubsection*{The old, for comparison}

Copyright \textcopyright

\end{document}


If I add \usepackage{fontspec} and compile with LuaLaTeX, I get

